# VBA Code to Close an Access Database Without Leaving a Shell of the application open

Tags: database, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

I'm currently using `Application.Quit` which leaves a shell of the MS Access Application open.

After processing the calling function against the target application, I am left with every instance of the application remaining open still; even though the specific database instance is closed.

**How do I make the database 'shell' application window close programatically using VBA?**

Here is an example of how the variable is created and how I am closing it:

```
Dim appAccess As New Access.Application

' Do stuff here...

appAccess.CloseCurrentDatabase
```

Comment: How are you invoking these 50 shells? Did you open each one of these manually, or were they opened by code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to execute Application.Quit against the instance variable.

For example,

```
Dim appAccess As New Access.Application

' Do stuff here...

appAccess.Application.Quit
```

Answer (score 10):

According to the documentation: [Application.Quit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff844963.aspx) does the same thing as [DoCmd.Quit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff191887.aspx). Namely

> The Quit method quits Microsoft Access. You can select one of several
>   options for saving a database object before quitting.

You can try calling either of them with the parameter `acQuitSaveNone` or 2 which "Quits Microsoft Access without saving any objects". Upon further review, use `Application.Quit` as `DoCmd.Quit` was [added for backward compatibility for Access 95](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa221549%28office.11%29.aspx) (See remarks for Quit Method as it applies to the DoCmd object.) Doing either of these should still do an automatic compact on close if you have the permissions, which may be the cause of you shells.

If that doesn't work for you, here is a somewhat extreme suggestion. Save this as a vbscript file and call it once you're truly done with Access. This will terminate all MSAccess processes on your windows pc, without compacting and repairing.

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colProcessList = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = 'msaccess.exe'")
For Each objProcess in colProcessList
    objProcess.Terminate()
Next
```

To call the script replacing [vbspath] with the actual path. If the path has spaces make sure to use double quotes and put it in quotes:

```
shell "cscript [vbspath]"
```

Answer (score 6):

I always use `DoCmd.Quit acQuitSaveAll`.
This works at least in Access 2000, 2003 and 2010 (that's where I've *seen* it work).

Answer (score 5):

`Access.Quit` works for me.  Maybe try that instead of `Application.Quit`?

If that doesn't solve it, your problem may be elsewhere, in which case please tell us more about this project.

Answer (score 4):

DoCmd.Quit acQuitSaveAll, Worked at long last. I tried all the other options before and a shell was still hanging back.

Answer (score 0):

Switch the form to Design view.
Set form's `BorderStyle` property to `None`.
On the **View** menu, click **Form View**. Note that the form's title bar is completely removed.